# Why bridging with one port?

Tags: networking, interface, network-bridge

AFAIK, I think configuring bridges in `/etc/network/interfaces` can connect one interface to another, and needs at least 2 ports.

In the example, there are 2 interfaces, with eth0 being physical one. The `br-mgmt` only connects to one interface (checking `brctl` sees that it only has one port).

What's the purpose of bridging with one port?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto br-mgmt
iface br-mgmt inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    address 10.0.0.2
    netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some context, it can be really anything!

That said, *usually*, you want to configure a bridge interface on a server which is a host for one or more Virtual Machines. Because you might (and usually you do) want the VM(s) to access the external (physical) network, you **should** have a pre configured bridge where the (virtual) interfaces of the VM(s) can join to.